# Using Flexbox, how do I programmatically move a div?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a `div` within a flex container. I need to programmatically position - change `top` and `left` - and size - change `width` and `height` this `div`. How do I do this. Flex ignores changes to `top` and `left` but does seem to accept changes to `width` and `height`.

Comment: [mcve] is required, because HTML (layout), CSS (flexbox), and JavaScript/jQuery (programmatically position),  are aspects of your question. Added HTML and CSS tags, but it's a matter of your preference to what you are comfortable with either JavaScript and/or jQuery.

Comment: @zer00ne I cannot see how jQuery is involved, why mention it?

Comment: @Kos you said *,"I need to programmatically position..."*, that in anybodies' universe means JavaScript at the very core and if you were familiar with this aspect of programming, jQuery is a *de facto* tag associated with JavaScript. So if you intend to programmatically position an element with Objective-C or something else, include that in your post.

Comment: @Kos thought you were OP. **correction:** OP said, *"I need to...* More to the point, it's common to see a post specifically include or exclude jQuery.

Comment: @zer00ne I agree that a lot of pages have been implemented using jQuery but I don't agree that it's any kind of standard for new projects. You have a ton of choices such as React or Angular or Ember...

Answer (score 0):

Top and Left will only affect it if you are setting the div's position. e.g. if you wanted to position it inside the container then you would set position: relative on the container and position: absolute on the div.

However it would be bad practise to use position on a flexbox item since flexbox allows you to easily align and position items itself. Have a look at [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) flexbox guide to understand how you can manipulate the flexbox properties.

Answer (score 0):

I actually found the answer. Set the container to `display:block` for the element I want to move interactively. This restores the default 'non-flex' context.